# How can I make this xml file valid so that I can view it in a well-formatted way?

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list, xml-visualizer

I'm debugging an issue which I suspect has to do with the data (it only happens once in a great while, and possibly is only when a particular record is used*). The data in question is a Sharepoint list. I have an xml representation of the data that I would like to look through to see if there any obvious problems.

- It is a 35-question test, and the 35 are randomly selected from a pool of 107 questions. So if it is one question/record that is the problem, it is only being used maybe a third of the time, and may only be a problem if a particular element therein is referenced (depending on the candidate answer the test-taker selects).

I wanted to view this in a way where the individual elements can be viewed more readily than what Notepad++'s XML view allows (records are simply jumbled together).

I downloaded XML Viewer from MIndFusion, but when I attempt to open the XML file it tells me, "Invalid at the top level of the document" and implicates this (first line):

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
```

What can I do to tweak the XML file to make it viewable? Or is there another viewer tool that will handle this better?

Comment: Maybe add this line to the top:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: It complains about that line when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part here:

```
xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
```

Is invalid.  An XMLNS can only have one : in it.

Notepad++ parses this fine for me using the XML Tools plugin - which does provide some pretty-printing functionality.  You might find that useful.  Otherwise I'd try removing the extra colon or replacing it with someing valid and viewing it in the other editor(s) you're trying.